# How to publish something on user's friend stream/wall in an application

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In a Facebook application, I need to publish a user's friend stream a mlessage.

how can i figure out of that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the javascript API for posting. The manual has sample code. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/

```
    FB.ui(
        {
            method: 'feed',
            to: friendId,
            name: 'title',
            link: 'http://host.com/title_link.com',
            picture: 'http://host.com/image.jpg',
            description: 'description',
            caption: 'caption',
         },
         function(response) {
            // Check for a posting to wall
            if (response && response.post_id) {
                // do some logging
            }
         }
       });
```

Comment: I have tried severals times yesterday and today it's working ... strange but good, thx

Comment: I noticed an problem if you have the picture URL is https instead of http (image doesn't load). Also, if you leave the description and/or caption blank, Facebook tries to scrape the URL to figure out values for those. If your site doesn't allow the scrape, you may have problems.

Answer (score 1):

send HTTP POST request to the following address https://graph.facebook.com/FRIEND_ID/feed
it returns the ID of posted message on success

here's the example code:

```
var msg = 'hello world';
FB.api('/YOUR_FRIEND_ID/feed', 'post', { message: msg }, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
  } else {
    alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
  }
});
```

Comment: you need to request `publish_stream` permission